# Minimum Degree of A Simple Graph that Ensures Connectedness

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G= \langle V, E \rangle$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices and minimum degree $\delta $. Show that if $\delta \geq \frac{n-1}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let $u,v$ be two vertices, and let $w_1,..,w_{n-2}$ denote the remaining $n-2$ vertices.

If $uv$ is an edge, this is a path from $u$ to $v$.

If $uv$ is not an edge, then $u$ respectively $v$ is connected to at least $\delta$ vertices from $w_1,..,w_{n-2}$. Together, $u$ and $v$ are connected to at least $n-1$ vertices from $w_1,..,w_{n-2}$.

Deduce that there is a common vertex $w$, which gives you a path $u-w-v$.

**Second solution** Assume by contradiction that $G$ is disconnected. Then one of the components must have at most $ \frac{n}{2} $ vertices. Then every vertex in this component has degree at most 
$$\frac{n}{2}  -1 < \frac{n-1}{2} =\delta$$