# Graph connectivity proof

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $n \geq 2$ and $p \geq 1$ be two positive integers. Let $G$ be a graph with n vertices such that each vertex has $p$ or more incident edges. Prove that if $p > \frac{n−2}2$ then $G$ is  connected.

I'm not sure how to tackle this one.

1. I guess that the Handshaking lemma might be relevant.
2. I guess that it might be easier to prove the contrapositive?

Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: you can use the pigeonhole principle to show that two non-adjacent vertices must have a shared neighbor.

Comment: @Fuseques, Thanks! how can I connect it to the n-2/2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum Degree of A Simple Graph that Ensures Connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429798/minimum-degree-of-a-simple-graph-that-ensures-connectedness)

Comment: This question and the proposed duplicate state the condition on $\delta(G)$ differently.  This question says that $\delta(G) > (n - 2)/2$, while the other says that $\delta(G) \geq (n - 1)/2$.  However, it is easy to check that because $\delta(G)$ is an integer, the conditions are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by Contradiction, 
    Let $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ be two component of $G$.
Let $n$ is even then take $ n = 2m \geq 2$ then $m \geq 1$. We need to find maximum possible degree of a vertex in both component $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$. WLOG we can take $|G_{1}| = |G_{2}| = m $ then maximum possible degree of $G_{1}$ or $G_{2}$ is $m-1$.
Also we have from given condition that $p > \frac{n-2}{2} = m-1$ Contradiction. Hence there must be edges between $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$. Graph is connected. 
Now Let $n = 2m+1$ be odd. Then take $|G_{1}|=m$ and $|G_{2}|=m+1$ and find maximum degree 
in both component. We get Maximum degree of $G_{1}$ as $m-1$ and same for $G_{2}$ as $m$.
Now minimum degree $p > \frac{2m+1-2}{2} = m-1 + \frac{1}{2}$ i.e. $p \geq m$ and we will not get this in $G_{1}$. Contradiction. Hence Connected.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood why is it a contradiction. Can you please elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: @Bob_Bobb Because maximum degree possible in both the component is $m-1$ when $n$ is even but it is given that minimum degree is greater than $m-1$. We are considering $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ as complete graph. There must be edges between both component to reach a minimum degree in $G$.